# What is the best way to generate primary key automatically?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to generate my primary key automatically in MySQL data table. But I want it to be a character string though in sequence.

Example: 
**user_id (Primary Key)**

USER000001

USER000002

USER000003

USER000004 ....and so on..

Comment: Forget the `user` part and just use an auto incremented integer.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yea that can be done. But I want it to be USER000001. Is there any way sql can do it by it self so that I don't have to write any code for that.

Comment: Use an normal auto-increment column and concatenate it to the string you want in your select query

Comment: Why does the primary key *need* to have this string value?  Can't that just be a matter for the display?  Maybe have an auto-increment column and a varchar column and use them as a composite PK?

Comment: Saving repetitive prefix for no reason is a waste. If you wanna show USER prefix on user interface, do something like `formatter.format("USER%06d", number)`

Answer (score -2):

By separate table for sequencing and a trigger, you can generate PK automatically with your format.

Tables

```
CREATE TABLE tableName_seq
(
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
);
CREATE TABLE tableName
(
  id VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT '0', name VARCHAR(30)
);
```

Now the trigger

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER tg_table_insert
BEFORE INSERT ON tableName
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO tableName_seq VALUES (NULL);
  SET NEW.id = CONCAT('USER', LPAD(LAST_INSERT_ID(), 6, '0'));
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Then you just insert rows to table

```
INSERT INTO tableName (name) 
VALUES ('Jhon'), ('Mark');
```

And you'll have

```
|         ID | NAME |
------------------
| USER000001 | Jhon |
| USER000002 | Mark |
```